# Limits of Dimensions and Metrics in Google Analytics API V4

Tags: google-analytics-api

Does anyone what is the number of dimensions and metrics are allowed in single Google Analytics API call.
I tried to search in this article  but not found anything

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the max number of dimensions in one batchGet reporting call is 9 and the max number of metrics is 10.

see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet